# How to use databasedotcom AggregateResult?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, salesforce, databasedotcom-gem

How do I use the AggregateResult I receive from a query using the databasedotcom gem?

```
quer = "SELECT SUM(MRR__c) FROM Account WHERE Type = 'Customer' AND Go_Live_Date__c > 2012-01-01 GROUP BY Producer__c"
ff = client.query quer
[#<SalesforceCont::AggregateResult:0x00000102e707b8 @Id=nil>, #   
<SalesforceCont::AggregateResult:0x00000102e70380 @Id=nil>, #
<SalesforceCont::AggregateResult:0x00000102e6ff48 @Id=nil>, #
<SalesforceCont::AggregateResult:0x00000102e6fb10 @Id=nil>]
```

I can not figure out how to use them. The in the documentation mentioned "get" or anything similar does not exist.

Comment: Also when I use the examples from Salesforce I only get those @Id=nil objects.   http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_query_aggregateresult.htm

Comment: Could you enable debugging in the client, then send the output from when you call client.query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The databasedotcom gem does not currently support AggregateResult. However, I encountered this same issue a while ago and made a quick-and-dirty fix that lets it return AggregateResults properly. It is available here: https://github.com/JackSullivan/databasedotcom